# Solving a nonlinear ODE 2. Order in Matlab numerically

Tags: matlab, numeric, numerical-methods, nonlinear-functions

I have a nonlinear-ODE of the second order with trigonometric functions such that I cannot formulate it depending of the second derivation. For example:

```
ay'' + b arctan(y'') + cy' + dy=0
y'(0)=0, y''(0)=0
```

**Without existence of** a term like **arctan(y'')** I could write my ode function like

```
function output=myodefunc(u,t){
  y(1)=u(2);
  y(2)=(-c*u(2)-d*u(1))/m;
  output=y';
}
```

**Unfortunately** the nonlinear term of the second order (=> b*arctan(y'') ) makes me unable to write the ode **in dependence of y''** .

Is there any way to solve such a trigonometric ode numerically in Matlab?

Comment: Are there any boundary conditions? Did you [consult Google](http://goo.gl/uIXkmm) regarding your problem first?

Comment: Yes of course I did. I could handle this problem with symbolic toolbox but even not numerically. I can not bring it in the y''(y,y') form so that I can use an ode solver. So I asked it here how to. I don't know what I did wrong to get a downvote..Please consult me

Comment: You might find [this blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/06/10/from-symbolic-differential-equations-to-their-numeric-solution/) helpful.

Comment: I unfortunately didn't. So I edit my question and define my problem more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can evaluate the y'' with a nonlinear solver (fsolve), within the ode function:

```
function output=myodefunc(u,t){
  y(1)=u(2);
  x0=0;
  x=fsolve('a*x + b*atan(x) + c*u(2) + d*u(1)',x0);
  y(2)=x;
  output=y';
}
```